# Href url for cloned Image component is always #

Tags: sxa

I have cloned the SXA Image Component by creating a new view file, new template and new rendering parameters template.

[image]

There is a `URL` field in the item and I have inserted an external link in here. I have also created a rendering variant with a single image field (Is Link set to true). But the output for the link (href) is always `#`.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The SXA image component does not work this wway.. it looks for the `TargetUrl` field from the Image datasource template (it uses the actual guid for this - `{54CAB1BA-53D3-4CE4-AB7E-F8C17596AA47}`).

The variant is rendered with this value (or `#` if not found) as a "href override". That is where the url comes from..

Without this, the "Is link" would link to the context item (at that moment), which would mean your link goes to the image item itself what would be pointless.

So if you want to customize the image component, use the original template as a base template for your own. This way you will have the TargetUrl field in your template.